# Grid alignment of 4 images

Tags: graphics, alignment, includegraphics, grids, subfig

[image: Current scenario]

I wanted to align the four images in a grid of 2x2, but the images are getting arranged vertically. I'm working on a template of IEEE format.
This is the code that I'm working on:

```
\begin{figure}[!tbp]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth,height=5cm,center]{MobileApp/Menu.png}
\caption{Menu}
\label{fig:menu}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth,height=5cm,center]{MobileApp/Cart.png}
\caption{Cart}
\label{fig:cart}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth,height=5cm,center]{MobileApp/Address.png}
\caption{Address selection}
\label{fig:address}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth,height=5cm,center]{MobileApp/Payment.png}
\caption{Payment screen}
\label{fig:payment}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Main screens of the application}
\label{fig:main}
\end{figure}
```

Any suggestions as to what needs to be done to get them arranged in a grid?

Comment: Because you are leaving an empty line between them. In TeX an empty line means a paragraph break. Remove the empty line and end the first and third subfigures with `\end{subfigure}%` (the `%` is important).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for the suggestion, it worked! Earlier I wasn't leaving a line though, but didn't add that % sign.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yup, now realized had the same mistake.

Comment: Good to know it worked :) I marked a duplicate for your question, which is essentially the same problem. My answer there explains why the `%` is important. Essentially, it's because when you have a line break TeX reads it as a space, then the width of the figures plus the space don't fit in the line so TeX breaks the line in that space. Adding the `%` removes that space so the subfigures are “glued” to each other.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for the explanation! Just started with tex so couldn't relate earlier XD

Comment: You're welcome :) In this case, welcome to TeX! Hope you enjoy your stay :)

Comment: Also, you appear to be in twocolumn mode, so you need figure" instead of figure.